# Trying to add a path to classpath through gradle or some other way

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, classloader

I have a gradle/SpringBoot project. I'm trying to run some junit tests that use 3rd party annotations to inject classes. The injected classes are creating a text file (call it 'foo.txt') under `$(PROJECT_DIR)/app/build/resources/test`. However the same injected class then uses a `classLoader.getReource("foo.txt")` to try to find the file to try to process it. The classLoader looks like it is searching for foo.text under `$(PROJECT_DIR)/build/resources/test` and since it can't find it there the 3rd party class throws an exception.

So I somehow either need to make classLoader.getResource() called from the 3rd party class search in `$(PROJECT_DIR)/app/build/resources/test` for foo.txt or make the 3rd party class create foo.txt in `$(PROJECT_DIR)/build/resources/test`.

I was thinking the way to resolve this might be to add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/app/build/resources/test` to the classpath in gradle for the test task. But I don't know how to add a new path to the classpath through gradle. I searched all over google but don't see any examples.

Also, If there is a better solution I'm open to that too, but I have limitations in how I can try to resolve this i.e. assume I can't change the 3rd party app for now, and can't refactor project structure of the project I am creating tests in.

**Update:**
In case it is helpful here is what the test/s looks like:

```
@ExtendWith({3rdPartyClassResolver.class})
public class 3rdPartyTest {
      
  //the actual failing test       
  @Test
  @3rdPartyClass(
    storageLocation = "https://storage-location.us/",
    application = "app1",
    version = "latest",
    requestor = "app2")
  public void testing3rdPartyClass(Map<3rdPartyClass, List<Event>> map) {
    System.out.println(); //I don't make it to this point
  }
  //this is what the 3rd party class is trying to do.
  //I'm able to reproduce it using this test. it fails the same way.
  @Test
  public void writeToFile() throws Exception {
    Path pathnio = Paths.get("build/resources/test/foo.txt");
    Files.write(pathnio, Collections.singleton("some text"));
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL resource = classLoader.getResource("foo.txt");
    assertNotNull(resource); //this assert fails
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the source code for the JUnit tests in question? That could potentially be helpful in trying to understand the situation and come up with some sort of suggestion to a solution :)

Comment: OK I updated the main post with some code.